# Usage of "broaden the perspective"

Tags: phrases, academia

I would like to ask if the phrase "broaden the perspective" can be used in academic papers or is there a way to write it better? The usage is the following:
"I believe that children should have opportunities to learn arts at school as it **allows them to broaden their perspective.**" What I want to say, is that learning art improves the ability to look at things from a different angle.

So far I have found more other options, but I am not sure whether they do mean the same and still if they can be used at all:

- broaden horizons
- broaden view

I would appreciate any provided help, thanks

Comment: A [broadened perspective](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/broader-perspective) would appear to mean what you want it to. Writing advice is off-topic, and I'm not sure how or even whether this question can be made on topic.

Comment: Broaden perspective has to do with how one relates to what they can see.  Broaden horizons has to do with increasing the scope of what they can see.  ‘View’ can be taken to mean either of those.

Comment: << "I believe that children should have opportunities to learn arts at school as this will allow them to broaden their perspective." What I want to say is that learning art improves the ability to look at things from a different angle. >> That addresses the problems with the English, but arts has mysteriously narrowed to art.